# Why is my Like query liked by Toad but not liked by C#?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, sql-like

If I run this query in Toad:

```
SELECT BANDID, BANDNAME
FROM WOODSTOCK
WHERE BANDNAME LIKE '%THE%'
```

..it works just dandy, and returns a bunch of rows. However, what is presumably the equivalent in code:

```
const string sql = @"SELECT BANDID, BANDNAME
            FROM WOODSTOCK
            WHERE BANDNAME LIKE '%:BANDNAMEPORTION%'";
. . .
ocmd.Parameters.Add("BANDNAMEPORTION", BandNamePortion);
. . .
```

...returns no records.

Comment: Don't know for sure, but do you have to escape the `%`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, "presumably the equivalent" clearly isn't equivalent, given that it doesn't work. Your parameter name is inside quotes, so it's not being treated as a parameter. I suspect you want:

```
const string sql = @"SELECT BANDID, BANDNAME
            FROM WOODSTOCK
            WHERE BANDNAME LIKE :BANDNAMEPORTION";
. . .
ocmd.Parameters.Add("BANDNAMEPORTION", "%" + BandNamePortion + "%");
```

Comment: I'm a String.Format() obsessive, so I made it (after changing the sql to "...upper(BANDNAME)...":       ocmd.Parameters.Add("BANDNAMEPORTION", String.Format("%{0}%", BandNamePortion.ToUpper()));

Comment: FYI: You've got a trailing quote on the param in the SQL - nevermind I'll fix it

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be

```
const string sql = @"SELECT BANDID, BANDNAME
        FROM WOODSTOCK
        WHERE BANDNAME LIKE '%' + @BANDNAMEPORTION + '%';";
. . .
ocmd.Parameters.Add("BANDNAMEPORTION", BandNamePortion);
```